# System.NotSupportedException: 'Optimistic concurrency for 'Taxes/353-A' is not supported when using a cluster transaction.' in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

We are using cluster-wide transactions and we get the error mentioned in the subject line when updating a document. To update the document, first, we load it from the database, modify some fields and then have it saved using the provided `ChangeVector` and the `Id`. My understanding is that supplying `ChangeVector` enables optimistic concurrency for that session only which is our intention.
Here is the code snippet:

```cs
var taxToUpdate = await session.LoadAsync<Tax>(myTax.Id, cancellationToken);
taxToUpdate.Description = "Updated description";
await session.StoreAsync(taxToUpdate , myTax.ChangeVector, myTax.Id, cancellationToken);
await session.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The stack trace reads as:

> Raven.Client.Documents.Session.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ValidateClusterTransaction(SaveChangesData
> result) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.1\51010\src\Raven.Client\Documents\Session\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line
> 883    at
> Raven.Client.Documents.Session.Operations.BatchOperation.CreateRequest()
> in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.1\51010\src\Raven.Client\Documents\Session\Operations\BatchOperation.cs:line
> 41    at
> Raven.Client.Documents.Session.AsyncDocumentSession.d__31.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.1\51010\src\Raven.Client\Documents\Session\AsyncDocumentSession.cs:line
> 157    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()

What is the solution for this problem as using `ChangeVector` is a must in our application's context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optimistic concurrency at the document level isn't supported.
It is handled using the compare exchange feature.

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/Csharp/server/clustering/cluster-transactions#case-1-multiple-concurrent-cluster-transactions